# for GPUImage, how to precompile shader and store it in the app

Tags: image-processing, gpuimage

Because my shader is about 3000 lines, it will take long time to compile, So I want to precompile it and store in the app, then cache it to memory when run the app.

Comment: How _long_ does the compilation take on a real device ? Apple provides some [best practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW4)

Comment: It take 0.02 second on iPhone 6 plus, but take about 2 seconds on my iPhone 4s. Maybe I need opt my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not with OpenGL ES on the iOS devices (per your comment). Metal lets you precompile shaders, but that's not used in GPUImage.

That said, if you have a 3000-line shader, you need to rethink your approach. The longest and most performance-intensive shader in the entire GPUImage framework is 86 lines long. A 3000-line fragment shader will perform terribly.

Try breaking this up into smaller sub-operations or rethinking this to avoid as much code (conditionals, etc.) as you possibly can.